# Установить текущее время с помощью командной строки

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, время, timezone

Нужно установить текущее время на машине с Ubuntu, графический интерфейс недоступен, только командная строка.

Нашёл такую инструкцию:

```
sudo date --set "23 Oct 2015 14:37:00"
```

Она мне не нравится тем, что

- Время будет неточным,
- Нужно формировать строку вручную.

Ещё есть вариант с настройкой автообновления через NTP, но хотелось бы более простое решение.

Есть ли другой, более точный и удобный способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ещё есть вариант с настройкой автообновления через NTP

для работы `ntpd` в актуальных версиях дистрибутивов операционной системы *gnu/linux* ничего настраивать не требуется (если доступ к интернету есть и порт `123/udp` не блокируется).

достаточно просто поставить соответствующий пакет (обычно он называется *ntp*) и хотя бы с точностью до минуты выставить системное время.

ntpd при запуске (и в процессе работы) будет регулярно синхронизировать время с серверами в интернете с точностью до (каких-то там) долей секунды.

первоначальная установка хотя бы приблизительного времени нужна ввиду того, что, если оно расходится более чем на 1000 секунд с общемировым (вроде бы такова умолчальная настройка), то ntpd прекращает работу, справедливо считая, что у данной машины что-то не совсем в порядке с системными часами.

одноразово установить время можно не только с помощью прогаммы `date`, но и, например, с помощью программы `ntpdate` из (обычно) одноимённого пакета, передав ей аргументом любое имя из любого [ntp-пула](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/NTPPoolServers):

```
$ sudo ntpdate europe.pool.ntp.org
```

Comment: Так не хочу я самостоятельно выставлять системное время. Это же неточно, да и неудобно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, добавил в ответ пару слов.

Comment: *Это же неточно, да и неудобно* — ну, один раз после установки дистрибутива можно ведь и ввести *приблизительное* текущее время (дальше ntpd справится). хотя, конечно, необязательно.

Comment: С парой слов стало гораздо понятнее.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл способ выполнения через пакет *tzdata*:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Одновременно делает следующее:

- Установка временной зоны (можно оставить ту же, что и раньше была)
- Синхронизирует время.

Дальнейшей автосинхронизации нет, но и этого оказалось достаточно.

Comment: для создания файла etc/ntp.conf не хватило прав, а для установки пакета хватило?

Comment: @ivanK. как ни странно, да. Там авторизация через LDAP, со своими странностями. Пока что разбираюсь с этим, как починю - отпишусь.

Comment: Просто если у вас есть доступ к root пользователю, вы можете что угодно делать в системе. Вряд ли Вы не через sudo пробовали создать файл с конфигурацией...

Comment: @ivanK. Да, мне это тоже кажется нелогичным. `sudo vim etc/ntp.conf`, при попытке сохранить (`:wq`) пишет `"etc/ntp.conf" E212: Can't open file for writing`

Comment: вообще-то `что-нибудь` — это относительный путь. относительно текущего каталога. абсолютный путь: `/что-нибудь`. а для работы ntp-демона не требуется редактировать файлы.

Comment: @alexander.
А разве права `sudo` не позволяют редактировать файлы(любые в том числе и системные)??

Comment: @ivanK. в текущем каталоге может не оказаться каталога `etc` и попытка редактирования файла `etc/что-нибудь` закончится неудачей для **любого** пользователя. даже для Ричарда Столмана.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin.
_))) А вот насчет того что каталога может не быть, я чет прогнал..

Comment: @ivanK. В файле /etc/sudoers можно разрешить пользователю выполнять только определённые действия, например только установку пакетов, от имени root, остальные запретить, так что ситуация "не хватило прав" возможна.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin действительно, дело было в `/`.